# Unable to access the value of QueryString outside the OnNavigatedTo method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

For the following code:

```
public string matchid;


protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        matchid = null;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("matchid", out matchid))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(matchid);     //statement1           
        }
     }

 public void display()
 {
    MessageBox.Show(matchid);    //statement2
 }
```

I am obtaining the output for statement1, whereas it is throwing ArgumentNullException for statement2. The variable 'matchid' is globally defined for both functions and yet its not keeping the value for display().

Is there any way I could get the value of matchid in display()???

Comment: One of two things is happening - either you have multiple instances of your class, or `display()` is called before `OnNavigatedTo`.

Comment: When does display get called?

Comment: when i am calling the constructor for the parent class, display is being called.

Comment: @user1320407 It makes sense then: if you call `display` from a constructor, then `OnNavigatedTo` has not been called yet, and so `matchid` remains `null`, no?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight & Ritch Melton thanks a ton... u r a life saver!!

Answer (score 1):

Once the global variable `matchid` is set in OnNavigated to, it will remain set and you should be able to use afterwards in any instance method in your `PhoneApplicationPage`'s class. The things that you need to look into are:

1. Do you assign `matchid` back to null before calling `display`, and as thus use matchid that is null and can't be used with MessageBox, or,
2. Do you call `display` after matchid is assigned in OnNavigatedTo?

You should specify information about *calls* to `display`.

Btw, you can access the NavigationContext outside OnNavigatedTo. You don't need to store it's values in global variables.